# Is it possible to open shared memory segment by name?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-memory

```
char* openSharedMemory(string name);
```

Is it possible to implement the function above? Given a name, open the shared memory segment with that name and return the handle to the shared memory. If shared memory with the given name does not exist, create one and return the handle.

Comment: What do you mean by a *shared memory segment*?

Comment: @BjörnPollex Just a block of memory shared between processes for communication.

Comment: This is Platform-dependent - which platform are you on?

Comment: With such a highly platform-dependent concept like shared memory, some notes about your platform would surely be useful.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Both Linux and Windows.

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: in that case, [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html) is the most portable way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portably, you can use [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html).

On Posix, you could do something like this:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const size_t SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE = whatever;

char* openSharedMemory(std::string const &name)
{
    int fd = shm_open(name.c_str(), O_RDWR, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        // failed to open existing file, try to create a new one
        fd = shm_open(name.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
        if (fd < 0 || ftruncate(fd, SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE) != 0) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return static_cast<char*>(
        mmap(NULL, SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));
}
```

Although you should wrap it in a class, to keep hold of the file descriptor so it can unmap and close the shared memory object on destruction.

Comment: I tried to compile your code using g++, only to get "undefined reference to shm_open" error :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, take a look at [`shm_overview(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) if you are on any recent Unix, [`shm_open(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory) supports this..

Answer (score 0):

If Windows, look into using a memory-mapped file.

Answer (score 0):

On windows look at [MemoryMappedFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) and CreateFileMapping with a name